# How to set draggable Map pin

Tags: ios, ios7, mapkit

I am developing an application in which I have included MapKit.
When first map is loaded at the time pin will be located at predefine place. And at that time drag-gable property of pin is set to NO. 
Now I want to do this..
When user press button Edit it will allow user to drag pin. And when user drag pin and locate it at new place it will show user pin location name and lat long.

Comment: Possible Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9995197/enabling-and-disabling-annotation-dragging-on-the-fly-ios-mapkit

Answer (score 1):

`MKAnnotationView` exposes the property `draggable` which can be set to enable dragging of each annotation added to map view.

The documentation for `MKAnnotationView` states:

> If YES, the associated annotation object must also implement the setCoordinate: method. The default value of this property is NO.

Subclass `MKAnnotationView` and implement the `setCoordinate` method.
Then in your `mapView:viewForAnnotation:` method, set the `draggable` property to `YES`.